# How to create war from ear

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, war, ear

I have developed a web-service client and tested it as ear on local jboss always. this ear work fine. Now I want to create war for this application. whenever I tries:

```
project:export:war file
```

in eclipse, it creates war without any third party dependency jars files added to it. This war does not gets deployed on jboss successfully.
Can anybody guide me hw to create war from ear.

Comment: A `war` should simply be a module inside the `ear`. You should be able to unzip the `ear` and use the `war` inside it, unless the `ear` has some weird shared library or classpath setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot create war from ear. ear is enterprise archive, and war is web archive.
 ear may contain many war files. So when you are creating war using eclipse, it creates a web archive.
 To add your third party jars, put them into the lib folder of your web application, that way it will be included into your war.